# If a controller conforms to a protocol then is it necessary for it to provide a body to all the methods of protocol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In Java, there is wrapper classes. but in objective c what is there any wrapper class or something else?

Answer (score 4):

In ObjectiveC protocol methods can be marked as @optional - those ones don't have to be implemented. e.g.

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@required

- (NSUInteger) methodOne;

@optional

- (NSUInteger) methodTwo; // Doesn't have to be implemented

@end
```

The method that calls the protocol should then check to see if the instance responds to that selector:

```
if ([anInstanceOfAClassThatImplementsMyProtocol respondsToSelector:@selector( )]) {
        [myProtocolInstance methodTwo];
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain me your 2nd line?

Comment: Which method is calling the protocol?

Comment: Typically, a class instance is calling a delegate which implements the protocol. See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html

Answer (score 2):

You wil get a warning if you dont implement obligatory methods in the protocol. A protocol is typically defined like this:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol<NSObject>
- (void)obligatoryMethod;
@optional
- (void)optionalMethod;
@end
```